# div size after an eventlistener

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I was working in this super simple project get really satisfied with the finish work but then CHAN! When I check the functionality of the app I noticed that the firs card, the one of the `basic` services get's bigger when the number change and also the third division line of the card change his size acting by himself when all the division lines are made it at once.
I was using `SASS` for this project but I don't think that was the problem in the compilation.

The problem is when I test the app in big screens

```js
const switcher = document.querySelector("input");

switcher.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const priceBasic = document.querySelector(".priceBasic");
  const pricePro = document.querySelector(".pricePro");
  const priceMaster = document.querySelector(".priceMaster");
  if (switcher.checked == true) {
    priceBasic.innerHTML = "$49.99";
    pricePro.innerHTML = "$69.99";
    priceMaster.innerHTML = "$89.99";
  } else {
    priceBasic.innerHTML = "$19.99";
    pricePro.innerHTML = "$24.99";
    priceMaster.innerHTML = "$39.99";
  }
});
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  background: #f7f6ff;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 980px;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 65px;
  height: 35px;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 14px;
  top: 3.1px;
  background: #eeeded;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background: #7466f5;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  transform: translateX(35px);
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 35px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  width: 35%;
  height: 75%;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.header-and-switch {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
}
.header-and-switch h2 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  color: #524c85;
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  .header-and-switch h2 {
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  .header-and-switch {
    margin-bottom: 3%;
  }
}

.switch-and-stuff {
  display: flex;
}
.switch-and-stuff h4 {
  margin: auto 25px;
  color: #b3b5c6;
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  .cards-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

.card {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.card h4 {
  color: #b3b5c6;
}
.card h1 {
  color: #170f61;
  font-size: 5rem;
  margin: 0px auto 10px auto;
}
.card div {
  width: 110%;
  height: 1.8px;
  background: #b3b5c6;
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  .card {
    margin: auto 20px;
  }
}

.btn {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 105%;
  height: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(115deg, #a3a8f0 35%, #696fdd 100%);
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:focus, .btn.focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.card:hover {
  transition: 0.5s ease-out;
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  background: linear-gradient(115deg, #a3a8f0 35%, #696fdd 100%);
}
.card:hover h4, .card:hover h1 {
  color: white;
}
.card:hover .btn {
  background: white;
}
.card:hover .btn a {
  color: #696fdd;
}
.card:hover .btn:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #696fdd;
}
.card:hover .btn:hover a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Change the price</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-and-switch">
            <h2>Our Pricing</h2>
            <div class="switch-and-stuff">
                <h4>Annually</h4>
                <div>
                    <label class="switch">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <h4>Monthly</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cards-container">
            <div class="card">
                <h4>Basic</h4>
                <h1 class="priceBasic">$19.99</h1>
                <div></div>
                <h4 class="features1">500 GB Storage</h4>
                <div></div>
                <h4 class="features">2 users Allowed</h4>
                <div></div>
                <h4 class="features">Send up to 3 GB</h4>
                <div></div>
                <button class="btn"><a href="#">LEARN MORE</a> </button>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <h4>Professional</h4>
                <h1 class="pricePro">$24.99</h1>
                <div></div>
                <h4 class="features1">500 GB Storage</h4>
                <div></div>
                <h4 class="features">5 users Allowed</h4>
                <div></div>
                <h4 class="features">Send up to 10 GB</h4>
                <div></div>
                <button class="btn"><a href="#">LEARN MORE</a> </button>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <h4>Master</h4>
                <h1 class="priceMaster">$39.99</h1>
                <div></div>
                <h4 class="features1">2 TB Storage</h4>
                <div></div>
                <h4 class="features">10 users Allowed</h4>
                <div></div>
                <h4 class="features">Send up to 20 GB</h4>
                <div></div>
                <button class="btn"><a href="#">LEARN MORE</a> </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You put an `h1` inside an `h1` in your event handler. Since the `h1` has a 10px margin at the bottom of it, that's at least one of the causes.

Comment: I changed it and the problem is still there

Comment: Apart from that, the problem is that the numbers have a width, and when you change the number the width changes, affecting the rest of the card. If you give the element that contains the number a fixed width, then when the number changes, the rest of the card wont change.

Answer (score 1):

what I would do:
the 2 prices are present on the interface but always with one or the other hidden.

example code of this system:

```js
const AllPrices = document.querySelectorAll('h1.price')

priceToggle.onclick=_=>
  {
  AllPrices.forEach(p=>p.classList.toggle('annual')) 
  }
```

```css
button {
  display:block; margin:2em
  }
.priceBlock {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: .5em;
  padding: .7em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: #85d5d8;
  color: navy;
}
h1.price span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
h1.price span:nth-of-type(2)        { height:0;    }
h1.price.annual span:nth-of-type(1) { height:0;    }
h1.price.annual span:nth-of-type(2) { height:auto; }
```

```html
<button id="priceToggle"> price toggle  </button>

<div class="priceBlock">
  <h1 class="price">
    <span>$19.99</span>
    <span>$500.99</span>
  </h1>
</div>

<div class="priceBlock">
  <h1 class="price">
    <span>$23.99</span>
    <span>$250.99</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```